# sonarqube-5.1.2 + PMD 2.4.1 plugin install does not work

Tags: exception, sonarqube, pmd

Today I installed the latest Sonarqube and I would have liked to install the pmd plugin from the update center but I got this error log.

BTW.: I could not install the findbugs plugin also because it is not available.

```html
2015.08.11 15:39:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.08.11 15:39:02 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonarqubedb
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1.2
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Issues Density / 1.0 / 4a8bae5f5611fa58b295494b6650457114da0ee4
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin StyleCop / 1.1 / 909438ebc609371919de34aa41262093711c58bc
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin ReSharper / 2.0 / f5844ba497b95ff618ffd7b312ac63b4fe4a3279
2015.08.11 15:39:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.2 / 307a76ec77a0b1f998d3de86d005d9e926164db4
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Android / 1.1 / 9ab2bbcc83177e67c74d365f009bfe05bf38c7e3
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Build Stability / 1.3 / adf81f731fc54be04431d4ccf753900c44ec33bd
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin JMeter / 0.3 / 454f502797c3c606a7260ffa30dd10551e6922c4
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Issue Assign / 1.6 / c24b76cdb882383411f58511cf9d8384f0539584
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Sonargraph / 3.4.2 / 1df390a29acc97509558c762de37aed053bf8429
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Git / 1.1 / 21e7329a632904350bb9a2e7f1b17b9967988db8
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin LDAP / 1.4 / 18ba3a13ba4c6c07e6b0ad77940a52734159c27e
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.1 / c37d9dc511fceca7d9a384e8a73e2cd76402719a
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 2.3 / 7c62fe8a00123b8df1fa16cc25ad77888e50e811
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin PMD / 2.4.1 / 2f30e0a7177041a4fb9f7ecefdb301e2bfc15903
2015.08.11 15:39:04 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to install plugin: DefaultPluginMetadata[key=pmd,version=2.4.1]
        at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.install(PluginJarInstaller.java:42) ~[sonar-core-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarInstaller.installToDir(ServerPluginJarInstaller.java:37) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarsInstaller.deploy(ServerPluginJarsInstaller.java:235) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarsInstaller.deployPlugins(ServerPluginJarsInstaller.java:217) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarsInstaller.install(ServerPluginJarsInstaller.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.start(ServerPluginRepository.java:49) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel2Container(Platform.java:106) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.copy(ZipUtils.java:144) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.unzip(ZipUtils.java:118) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarInstaller.extractPluginDependencies(ServerPluginJarInstaller.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.copyDependencies(PluginJarInstaller.java:49) ~[sonar-core-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.plugins.PluginJarInstaller.install(PluginJarInstaller.java:40) ~[sonar-core-5.1.2.jar:na]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_79-b15 [linux-amd64]
2015.08.11 15:39:04 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.08.11 15:39:12 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.get(JRubyFacade.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getDatabase(JRubyFacade.java:209) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:95) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:184) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1156) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1114) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:838) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2727) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:359) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1107) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(RubyKernel.java:1094) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:419) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:396) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsRackApplicationFactory.createApplicationObject(RailsRackApplicationFactory.java:22) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$1.create(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$RackApplicationImpl.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:420) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:111) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.doInit(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:94) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
2015.08.11 15:39:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Error listenerStart
2015.08.11 15:39:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2015.08.11 15:39:12 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015.08.11 15:39:12 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015.08.11 15:39:12 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8999"]
2015.08.11 15:39:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.08.11 15:39:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTPS connector enabled on port 8999 | ciphers=JVM defaults
2015.08.11 15:39:12 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isReady(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isReady(WebServer.java:45) [sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:80) ~[sonar-process-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
2015.08.11 15:39:12 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8999"]
2015.08.11 15:39:13 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8999"]
2015.08.11 15:39:13 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8999"]
2015.08.11 15:39:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2015.08.11 15:39:13 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested it and it works perfectly:

```
...
2015.08.12 10:32:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin PMD / 2.4.1 / 2f30e0a7177041a4fb9f7ecefdb301e2bfc15903
2015.08.12 10:32:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.0 / 213fc8a8b582ff530b12dd4a59a6512be1071234
2015.08.12 10:32:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
...
```

Your JAR is probably corrupted. You should uninstall it and download it again.

As a side note: the rules implemented by SonarQube Java plugin already cover everything that PMD provides - so you don't really need this plugin.